# CSS - Website trails off the screen on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

my website is essentially styled to be a full screen site, taking up any available space it can to show the website. As a result, the contents of the page has to automatically adjust to the screen size it's displaying on.

For some elements I have used `float` so that paragraphs can appear side-by-side to each other, and as a result I had to `float` the footer so that if the height of the content area increases the footer will move down to accommodate for the extra space the main text needs to take up.

Without `float`, the footer will not move down and the main content will overflow on to it should someone have a narrow screen.

Because of this, the main content area and the footer trails off the side of the screen on an iPad. I know this is an issue with the `float` because the header doesn't do it; only the content area and the footer.

I would like to fix this but not sure what to do.

The website is http://neerajmorar.co.uk

It works perfectly on PC, Linux and I assume the Mac since it works fine on Safari, but not on the iPad.

HTML code for index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Neeraj Morar | Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is the personal website of Neeraj Morar.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Neeraj, Morar, neerajmorar, neerajmorar.co.uk, personal, website, portfolio, home, computing, information, systems, university, of, west, london, sql, server, web, design">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="k3NDZl5POUlqaDoEEOTdrX50XrOcQ9nmQr9IFJK1NlU" />
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="6F4E786D9BE746A1AC789E62D2C0F961" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>(function (a, b) { if (/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) window.location = b })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://m.neerajmorar.co.uk');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".content").css("display", "none");
            $(".content").fadeIn(5000);
            if ($(".header a").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                linkLocation = this.href;
                $(".content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
            }));
            else if ($(".transition").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                linkLocation = this.href;
                $(".content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
            }));

            function redirectPage() {
                window.location = linkLocation;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="index">
            <li><a href="index.html">NeerajMorar.co.uk</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="computingskills.html">Computing Skills</a></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="webdesign.html">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="hello">
                <h2>Hello, I'm Neeraj</h2>
                <p>Business Systems Apprentice at Stanmore College, Student at University of West London, and TIME's Person of the Year 2006. (No, seriously, it's true!)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="taken">
                <h2>I have a very particular set of skills...</h2>
                <p>Oh, boy, do I! Pianist at heart (or a pedantic Organist, depending on how you look at it), a Black Belt in Tae Kwon Do, and a true nerd - not a skill, but I thought it would be nice to throw it in there!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="site">
                <h2>This site?</h2>
                <p>This website has been designed to give you an overview of who I am and what I do; it's a chance for you to be seduced by me! Please feel free to look around, and don't hesitate to <a href="contact.html" class="transition">contact me</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/">
                <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/badge/html5-badge-h-css3.png" width="133" height="64" alt="HTML5 Powered with CSS3 / Styling" title="HTML5 Powered with CSS3 / Styling">
            </a>
            <small>&#169; Copyright 2013 by Neeraj Morar. All Rights Reserved.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Skolar OT";
    src: url("fonts/SKOLAR-REGULAR-PVT.OTF");
}

html
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body
{
    font-family: "Skolar OT", Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: larger;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.header
{
    height: 224px;
    background-color: #ab0000;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #696969;
}

.index
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 44%;
    width: 505px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

    .index li
    {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 300%; 
    }

    .nav
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -83px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 670px;
        background-color: #780000;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    }

        .nav li
        {
            display: inline;
            font-size: x-large;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

.links
{
    border-style: none solid none none;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.header a
{
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

    .header a:hover
    {
        color: #d2d2d2;
    }

.box
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 560px;
    border-style: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 25px;
}

.content
{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer
{
    float: left;
    width: 97.45%;
    background-color: #780000;
    height: 83px;
    padding: 25px;
}

    .footer small
    {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        top: 10px;
        color: #e6e6e6;
    }

.hello
{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.taken
{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.site
{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.about
{
    width: 47.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.job
{
    width: 47.5%;
    float: left;
}

.ambition
{
    width: 47.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.other
{
    width: 47.5%;
    float: left;
}

.compute
{
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: larger;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.web
{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.software
{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.web2
{
    max-width: 700px;
    font-size: x-large;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contact
{
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-right: 22%;
}

#smooth
{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

fieldset
{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

textarea
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.5);
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

input[type="text"]
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.5);
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

input[type="email"]
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.5);
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

li a.transition
{
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

    li a.transition:hover
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    li a.transition:active
    {
        color: #000;
    }

.content p a.transition
{
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

    .content p a.transition:hover
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .content p a.transition:active
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

.a1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

    .a1:hover
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

#a1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

    #a1:hover
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

You can just view the source code of my website and the style sheet from there...

Answer (score 0):

Try using clear:both before footer and use overflow:hidden in your content area. That way you can get rid of the floats.